# Datatable - Tabletool Exporting all data to Excel rather the searched result

Tags: jquery, excel, datatable, datatables, tabletools

I'm using dataTable & TableTool.
Suppose I've 57 entries in the table like

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd_gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0 (focus once)</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
........................................................
```

Then I added all the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/TableTools.js"></script>
```

Next initialized with

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready( function () {
                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oTableTools": {
                        "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf" }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
```

Then I fetched the page on **localhost**. So it worked. It can print,it can take data to excel. But it's always exporting 57 entries after I search for something.

Suppose I searched 'something' & datatable returned me 8 entries that matched. Now I want to export this 8 data to excel not 57 entries. In this [Example link](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) it's working the way I want to, but not on my localhost. Is there anything that I'm missing? Or can it be a problem of the version for tabletool that I'm using? I'm not sure which version I'm using currently.

Comment: try to open your tabletools.js and figure out what version you are running locally...also is this a client side or server-side data implementation?

Comment: 2.1.6-dev & client side @JayRizzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was wrong but got the solution.
Checked the dataTable site with firebug. They are using a js file named '`complete.min.js`'

Downloaded that, used the  `complete.min.js` before `jquery.dataTables.min.js`
Removed the `ZeroClipboard.js` script.

And everything worked fine then.

Comment: As of 22-Sep-2014 the demo page in the example link does not work either. Do you still have copies of the "files"? can you post them or their hashes?

Comment: Do you still have copies of the "files"? i tried but that are not found

Comment: complete.min.js ? yes I have that @papa.ramu

Comment: can u give me that am having same issue for that i asked one question to solve if you provide me it helps me

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420724/data-table-search-filtered-output-are-not-exporting`

Comment: @papa.ramu http://www.mediafire.com/download/mjcfa80v53c53bf/complete.min.js here is the file

Comment: no , again it export all values no filtered output exported